# Why are primes of the form p^2 - 2 for prime p seemingly unusually likely to be factors of prime-exponent Mersenne numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The sequence [A049002](https://oeis.org/A049002) (primes of form $q^2 - 2$, where $q$ is prime) appears to contain a high proportion of elements that are factors of prime-exponent Mersenne numbers (see below). I wonder why?

Factors of Mersenne numbers must obey certain well-known properties (e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers)), but as a layperson I can't think of any obvious way to relate the above empirical result to those properties.

- 2, 7, **23**, **47**, **167**, **359**, **839**, **1367**, 1847, **2207**, 3719, 5039, 7919, **10607**, *11447*, 16127, 17159, 19319, 29927, 36479, **44519**, 49727, **54287**, **57119**, **66047**, **85847**, 97967, **113567**, **128879**, 177239, **196247**, **201599**, 218087, **241079**, 273527, 292679, **323759**, **344567**, 368447, **426407**, 458327, 516959, **528527**, **537287**, 552047, 563999, 573047, **579119**, 635207, 657719, 744767, 776159, 
  **1026167**, 1042439, 1104599, 1142759, **1190279**, *1329407*, **1495727**, 1515359, 1661519, **1682207**, **1708247**, 1745039, **1868687**, 1985279, ...

Of the 66 elements of A049002 less than 2 million, 32 of them are factors of prime-exponent Mersenne numbers. Of these, 30 of them are of the form $2p+1$; the other two are of the form $2kp+1$ ($11447=2*59*97+1$ is a factor of $M_{97}$ and $1329407=2*13*51131+1$ is a factor of $M_{51131}$).

Since all elements but the first are odd, we can write $q^2 - 2 = 2n + 1$ for some integer $n$. Empirically over this limited dataset, it seems that $n$ is prime almost half the time, which seems surprisingly high; also, if $n=p$ is prime, then empirically over this dataset it seems that $2p+1$ is always a factor of $M_p$ (recall that $2p+1$ is always prime by the construction of the sequence).

In the general case of $p$ and $2p+1$ both being prime, it is not necessarily true that $2p+1$ is a factor of $M_p$ (counterexamples include $p$ = 29, 41, 53, 83, etc). However, for any prime $p$ such that $2p+1$ is an element of A049002, it seems that $2p+1$ is always a factor of $M_p$ (at least over the limited dataset).

Is there any interesting math here, or at least some way to prove something or derive a result?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, never mind. The answer was there all along in the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers) I posted:

7. If $p$ and $2p + 1$ are both prime (meaning that $p$ is a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime)), and $p$ is congruent to 3 (mod 4), then $2p + 1$ divides $2^p − 1$.

The specific sequence A049002 has nothing to do with it, it's just a list of primes after all, and in most any list of primes some of them will be congruent to 3 (mod 4) and some will be congruent to 1 (mod 4).

I originally phrased the question a different way, focusing on a different angle, and spent some time editing it before posting it. After it ended up being worded the way it is now, I could have just reread that Wikipedia link and found out the answer myself.